# php-fpm version 5.4 with nginx constantly restarting

Tags: php, nginx, php5, php-fpm

I just upgraded my php version from 5.3.x to 5.4.x and since doing this - memory has dropped signifincantly! - however, I'm constantly getting these in my php5-fpm.log:

```
[18-Sep-2012 15:11:34] WARNING: [pool www] child 8981 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV - core dumped) after 65.813370 seconds from start
[18-Sep-2012 15:11:34] NOTICE: [pool www] child 8988 started
[18-Sep-2012 15:12:09] WARNING: [pool www] child 8988 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV - core dumped) after 35.185071 seconds from start
[18-Sep-2012 15:12:09] NOTICE: [pool www] child 8990 started
[18-Sep-2012 15:12:17] WARNING: [pool www] child 8990 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV - core dumped) after 8.277977 seconds from start
[18-Sep-2012 15:12:17] NOTICE: [pool www] child 8992 started
[18-Sep-2012 15:12:18] WARNING: [pool www] child 8982 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV - core dumped) after 109.550089 seconds from start
[18-Sep-2012 15:12:18] NOTICE: [pool www] child 8995 started
[18-Sep-2012 15:12:18] WARNING: [pool www] child 8985 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV - core dumped) after 109.668554 seconds from start
[18-Sep-2012 15:12:18] NOTICE: [pool www] child 8996 started
```

From what I can gather this is php silently dying?  I'm running basic Wordpress sites that keep popping up with 502 errors while php-fpm is constantly spinning up new processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this I ended up downgrading back to PHP 5.3.x.  Clearly WordPress sites (or maybe just the plugins being used) are not fully support for PHP 5.4.x.

Answer (score 2):

PHP 5.4 is still kind of new, and [crash bugs are being fixed](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php) all the time.

1. Update to the latest version of PHP, currently 5.4.7.
2. If the latest version of PHP still crashes, [report a bug](https://bugs.php.net/how-to-report.php).

Comment: is there a way to install to a specific version with apt-get install? as when i upgraded this morning it grabbed version 5.4.6

Comment: upgrading unfortunately did not work

Comment: Go to step 2, then.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that you re-compiled all your PECL extensions with the newer version of `php5-dev`? PHP can still start with extensions compiled for an older version - but can have very unpredictable behaviour.

**Just note**, that if you see errors **like this** (not like yours), it is quite normal. It is just a thread exiting after its max number of requests.

`[18-Sep-2012 15:51:36] NOTICE: [pool www] child 24737 exited with code 0 after 7657.928233 seconds from start`

If you want to upgrade/change your PHP version - you can either compile from source or use the [DotDeb](http://www.dotdeb.org/instructions/) repo. Although, as of writing only [5.4.6~1](http://archives.dotdeb.org/dists/squeeze/php5/5.4.6/binary-amd64/) is available.

Comment: I was able to upgrade to 5.4.7.  How do I check if my PECL extensions are recompiled?

Comment: They won't be unless you compile them again yourself. Ie. Any extensions you added after installing the base `php` install **not** via `aptitude` (eg. via `phpize; ./configure; make install`). Only you will know which they are :) You can look at the extensions using this command `ls $(php -i | grep extension_dir | cut -f 3 -d " ")`

Comment: it's not exiting with an exit code 0: child 3901 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV - core dumped) after 64.000948 seconds from start